# Why is it the body clipping through shinkwrapped shirt?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, armature, bones

I shrink wrapped my shirt, set the offset to 30, made a thickness from the solidify, weighted the armature move with the shirt, and yet some of the mesh or the normal's clip through the shirt when I rotate a bone. why?

[image]

Comment: Looks like some weights for the bones which are rotating weren't assigned accordingly. It might help in this case to edit manually weights for bones which control that area

Answer (score -1):

You need more geometry in the armpit.

Comment: It would be good if you could add some information as to *why* more geometry is needed.